# MvxTabBarViewController tab bar tint color

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to find a way to change the tab bar tint color when using MvxTabBarViewController. This does not work:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        // ios7 layout
        if (RespondsToSelector(new Selector("edgesForExtendedLayout")))
            EdgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None;

        if (ViewModel == null)
            return;

        var viewControllers = new UIViewController[]
                              {
                                CreateTabFor(ViewModel["Today"], "icon1", ViewModel.TodaysExercisesView),
                                CreateTabFor(ViewModel["Exercises"], "icon2", ViewModel.ExercisesView),
                                CreateTabFor(ViewModel["Progress"], "icon3", ViewModel.ProgressView)
                              };
        ViewControllers = viewControllers;
        CustomizableViewControllers = new UIViewController[] { };
        SelectedViewController = ViewControllers[0];

        // Causes null reference error
        this.TabBarController.TabBar.TintColor = UIColor.Blue;

    }
```

What would be the correct way to do this?
(Edited. Original question was about navigation bar tint as opposed to tab bar, which I actually meant)

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution.

```
UITabBar.Appearance.BarTintColor = UIColor.Blue;
```

This changes the style globally, which is what I wanted. The code can placed in ViewDidLoad or apparently elsewhere.

More info on Appearance API on Xamarin documentation here:
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/introduction_to_the_appearance_api/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in `ViewDidLoad()` without any issues:

```
this.TabBar.TintColor = UIColor.Blue;
```

This also gives you individual control, rather than a global setting.